# Selenium: searching children of a By locator in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an enum list of By locators for WebElements on a page. I want to be able to select a specific option of a select box using a combination of the enum as well as additional information of the value of the option I wish to select. Is there any way to do this? I notice that the `By` class also has the method `findElement(searchContext)`. Could I use this as something along the lines of:

```
public enum Dictionary {

    TYPE                        (By.id("vehType")),
    PROVINCE                    (By.id("provId")),
    TERRITORY                   (By.id("territoryId")),
    STAT_CODE                   (By.id("statCodeId")),
    CLASS                       (By.id("class1Id"));

    private final By locator;

    private DetailVehicleDictionary (By value) {
        this.locator = value;
    }

    public By getLocation() {
        return this.locator;
    }
}
```

And then if CLASS is a select box with HTML of:

```
<select id="class1Id" name="select_box">
    <option value="1"/>
    <option value="2"/>
    <option value="3"/>
</select>
```

Can I do something along the lines of:

```
WebElement specificValue = driver.findElement(Dictionary.CLASS.getLocation().findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value=2]"));
```

I need to have access to the actual element so that I can wait for the value to be present in the DOM. I plan on implementing this in a wait command such as:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(specificValue));
```

Comment: You can perform a `findElement` on the results of a `findElement`, but alec's solution is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium has a [special mechanism](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) to handle "select/option" cases:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;  // this is how to import it

WebElement select = driver.findElement(Dictionary.CLASS.getLocation());
Select dropDown = new Select(select); 
dropDown.selectByValue("1");
```

---

Answer to a follow-up question: use an [*Explicit Wait*](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement select = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElement(Dictionary.CLASS.getLocation()));
```

In case of waiting for an option to load inside a select, I am afraid, you would need to make a custom `ExpectedCondition` (not tested):

```
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> selectContainsOption(
    final WebElement select, final By locator) {

    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
                return elementIfVisible(select.findElement(locator));
            } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement select = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElement(Dictionary.CLASS.getLocation()));
WebElement option = wait.until(selectContainsOption(select, By.cssSelector('.//option[@value = "1"]')));
```

Comment: I would use this; however, I am trying to wait for this element to exist on the page. The website I am working with makes many AJAX calls and the best solution I have come to is waiting for the presence of the individual values within the select box before selecting them.

Comment: The problem is that the webpage has poor Ajax calls and sometimes updates the values within the select between finding the element, and waiting to select an option inside it. I need to wait for the specific option to be within the specific select

Comment: @bagelmakers I've updated the answer and included a possible solution - try it. Thanks.

Comment: What/where is `elementIfVisible` in this example?

Comment: @ChrisR sure, it is coming from [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c9e6405fe2660b8b9553e4aa4195f5c726b4ec95/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L301).

Comment: That method is in ExpectedCondition**s** but your example is ExpectedCondition (interface) which has no method called that. I'm getting `The method elementIfVisible(WebElement) is undefined for the type new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){}` when trying to implement something similar to this.

Comment: I have found that there are now methods available in Selenium to handle this situation with an ExplicitWait without the need for a custom ExpectedCondition making this much easier than it used to be. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37949079/184325) for how to implement using it.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar to you - use a `WebDriverWait` with an `ExpectedConditions` so that I could wait for the element to be there and located it as a child element relative to an existing one.

Additional methods are now available in Selenium to handle this:

`static ExpectedCondition<WebElement>   presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(By locator, By sub_locator)`
An expectation for checking child WebElement as a part of parent element to present

`static ExpectedCondition<WebElement>   presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(WebElement element, By sub_locator)`
An expectation for checking child WebElement as a part of parent element to be present

`static ExpectedCondition<java.util.List<WebElement>>   presenceOfNestedElementsLocatedBy(By locator, By sub_locator)`
An expectation for checking child WebElement as a part of parent element to present

**So for your case you could do the following:**

```
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(Dictionary.CLASS.getLocation(), By.cssSelector("option[value=2]")));
```

See here for the Javadocs: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-org.openqa.selenium.By-